# Split a string if a substring is present

Tags: regex, scala

I have two strings like:

"Nikon Coolpix AW130 **16MP** Point and Shoot Digital Camera Black with 5x Optical Zoom"

"Nikon Coolpix AW130 **16 MP** Point & Shoot Camera Black"

I am trying to compare strings like these, as you can see both of them are same, when I tokenize based on space and compare each word the space between 16 and MP in 2nd string will cause a difference which is not actually there.

Is there anyway I can add a space in the 1st string where the 16MP is together so that I can tokenize based on space properly.

```
val productList=List("Nikon Coolpix AW130 16MP Point and Shoot Digital Camera Black with 5x Optical Zoom","Nikon Coolpix AW130 16 MP Point & Shoot Camera Black")
val tokens = ListBuffer[String]()
  productList.split(" ").foreach(x => {
      tokens += x
  })

  val res = tokens.toList
```

Comment: `replaceAll("\\b16 MP\\b", "16MP")`? Or `replaceAll("\\b16MP\\b", "16 MP")`

Comment: what do you exactly want? compare the two strings regardless of space?

Comment: Could you describe the format of these strings ? I think you don't want us to give you an answer which is specific to these examples

Comment: By the way `productList.flatmap(_.split(" ")).toList` would be more elegant and has the same performance

Comment: yes i want to compare strings which have parts like 16MP/16 MP or 20MP/20 MP. As you can see both the strings are same but some have space between 20 and MP and some don't which is causing problems in comparison.

Comment: why dont you remove the space and compare then?

Comment: @Naba where do these strings come from ? Do they follow a well-defined fomat ?

Comment: @Dici I am actually getting these strings from Spark RDD, just created the list for simplicity, I am trying to do product matching from different sellers selling the same product online using number of  words matching in both product name.

Comment: @Naba ok that's not what I meant. They come from a database or something, I guess. If they have a well-defined format, just write a regex for it

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to remove the space between a number and a fixed `MP` string, you can use the following regex:

```
scala> "Nikon Coolpix AW130 16 MP Point & Shoot Camera Black".replaceAll("""(\d+) ?(MP)""", "$1$2")
res13: String = Nikon Coolpix AW130 16MP Point & Shoot Camera Black
```

- The `(\d+)` part matches any number with at least 1 digit
- The `?` (note the space) matches 0 or one spaces
- The `(MP)` part matches the string `MP` literally.
- `$1$2` prints the contents of the match of the first parentheses `(\d+)` appended to the match of the second parantheses `(MP)` - omitting the space, if there is one.

After that, the `16MP` tokenS should be equal. You will still have the problem of `and` vs. `&`, though.

Comment: Great!!! it's what I wanted also added few more patterns like :                       str.replaceAll("""(\d+) ?(MP|GB|mm|cm)"""

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with RegEx. 
Search both format and replace it to one specific. 
[image: RegeEx Test]

Answer (score 0):

You don't give enough details about the format of these strings but from this example I can infer something like that : `(\w+) (\d+)\s*MP Point.*`

You can then parse the strings and read the groups of the regex to compare the product.

Here is an example :

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {   
    val s0 = "Nikon Coolpix AW130 16MP Point and Shoot Digital Camera Black with 5x Optical Zoom"
    val s1 = "Nikon Coolpix AW130 16 MP Point & Shoot Camera Black"
    println(Product.parse(s0) == Product.parse(s1)) // prints true
}

case class Product(name: String, resolution: Int)
object Product {
    private val regex = new Regex("(\\w+) (\\d+)\\s*MP Point.*", "productName", "resolution")
    def parse(s: String) = regex.findFirstMatchIn(s) match {
        case Some(m) => Product(m.group("productName"), m.group("resolution").toInt)
        case None    => throw new RuntimeException("Invalid format")
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of split it is easier to do regex replaces; consecutively.

```
public static boolean equivalent(Sting a, String b) {
     normalize(a).equalsIgnoreCase(normalize(b));
}

private static String normalize(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("(\\d+)", "$0 ") // At least one space after digits.
        .replaceAll("\\bLimited\\b", "Ltd") // Example.
        .replace("'", "") // Example.
        .replace("&", " and ")
        .replaceAll("\\s+", " ") // Multiple spaces to one.
        .trim();
}
```

Or do a split on the normalized string (to get keywords).